# Is there a Devise method for getting current user's id without querying the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way to get the `id` of the currently logged-in user without having to access the database?

If you get the user's `id` by calling `current_user.id`, it creates a DB query and gets it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session["warden.user.user.key"][1][0]` to get current user id from session